# Junit BeforeAll or BeforeEach - when to initialise class under test if state does not change between tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit-jupiter

In my following example I am unsure if I should use `BeforeEach` or `BeforeAll` - Note the class under test `Calculator` does not change state etc between tests so I assumed making it `static` and using `BeforeEach` is more efficient?

```
public class CalculatorShould {

    private static Calculator calculator;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        calculator= new Calculator();
    }

    @Test
    void calculatePriceForTwo() {

        // act
        Double price = calculator.calculatePrice(2);

        // assert
        assertEquals(10, price);
    }

    @Test
    void calculatePriceForFour() {

        // act
        Double price = calculator.calculatePrice(4);

        // assert
        assertEquals(20, price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your example you don't need either `BeforeAll` or `BeforeEach`.

Instead, it's simpler (less code is good) to just declare:

```java
public class CalculatorShould {

    private Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    // test methods unchanged...
}
```

JUnit will provide you with a brand new instance of the `Calculator` before each test method is run:

> In order to allow individual test methods to be executed in isolation and to avoid unexpected side effects due to mutable test instance state, JUnit creates a new instance of each test class before executing each test method (see Test Classes and Methods). This "per-method" test instance lifecycle is the default behavior in JUnit Jupiter and is analogous to all previous versions of JUnit.

Source: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle

Comment: do you mean declare it in each test? before if I declare it outside each test method then each test cant access as its outside the scope?

Comment: Not in each test, but as a field. I updated the sample.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this give a new instance before each test? Is each test not just reusing the same calculator object?

Comment: It will only reuse the same instance if you declare the `Calculator` as a `static` field. If it's not `static`, a new instance will be created. I added a link to the documentation that has more details.

Comment: appreciate it, answer accepted!